# QGIS and batch processing: Is there a procedure to fill multiple parameters using arrays?

Tags: qgis, batch

I'm trying to calculate hillshades (Raster analysis -> Hillshade) for different time of the year, using batch processing and different input values for Azimuth and Altitude of light.

I figured out how to set the parameter Azimuth of the light using “Add value by expression...“ [dummy exemple: array(45, 50, 55, 60)]. I get four new lines filled with the expected azimuth values and the default value for Altitude of the light (45.0).

If I then set the altitude following the same procedure (“Add value by expression...“, array(100, 110, 120, 130)), I get 4 new lines filled with expected values for Altitude and default value for Azimuth (315.0).

Is there a procedure to set both Azimuth and Altitude in each line using arrays?